# New Relational Fields Added wont appear on DjangoRestFramework API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some issue here about the relational field `(herd/herd_id)` added to my model. it wont appear in the API as fields of my `Animal` model and `AnimalSerializer` `djangorestframework`

Here is my Animal model and serializer:

**models.py**

```
class Animal(models.Model):

    this_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    species_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    birth_weight = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    sibling_order = models.IntegerField()
    sire_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sire_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    dam_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    dam_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    rf_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)

    herd = models.ForeignKey(Herd, related_name='animals', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = (
            'this_id',
            'name', 
            'species_type', 
            'breed', 
            'date_of_birth', 
            'birth_weight', 
            'sibling_order', 
            'sex',
            'sire_id', 
            'sire_name', 
            'dam_id', 
            'dam_name', 
            'rf_id', 
            'comment', 
            'herd_id', // <--- this field wont appear in the djangorestframework UI.
            'created_at', 
            'updated_at',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

**Here is the image. and look for the `herd_id` field it wont appear. Please help**

[image: djangorestframework]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the `herd_id` to `herd` column name so django will recognize the matching serialization name.